# Excel, VB - Serialize an 8 digit date to mm/dd/yy

Tags: date, types, excel, casting, vba

## ISSUE

I am trying to convert a 8 digit number into a date while in an array. Examples of the entries are 12282009 or 12202007. There are other malformed entries in the field including dates entered as strings. I want the 8 digit number to be formatted as 12/28/09 or 12/20/07 respectively. **I keep getting a type mismatch error on the third to last line below. How do I do this??**

## CODE

```
Dim del()
ReDim del(1 To importwsRowCount, 1 To 1)
del = Range("AH1:AH" & importwsRowCount).Value
Dim delChars As Long
Dim delType As String
For i = LBound(del, 1) To UBound(del, 1)
    delChars = Len(del(i, 1)) 'Determine length of entry
    If IsNumeric(del(i, 1)) = True Then 'Determine datatype of entry
        delType = "Numeric"
        del(i, 1) = Abs(del(i, 1))
    Else
        delType = "String"
        del(i, 1) = UCase(del(i, 1))
    End If     
If delType = "Numeric" Then
    If delChars = 8 Then
        del(i, 1) = DateSerial((Right(del(i, 1), 4)), (Left(del(i, 1), 2)), (Mid(del(i, 1), 3, 2))) '<-- TYPE MISMATCH ERROR
    End If
End If
```

## ENTRY TEMPLATES

**SEPT. 25, 20** (No year, no year! Delete.)
**SEPT** (No year, useless, delete.)
**N/A** (Rubbish! Deleted.)
**LONG TIME AG** (What moron thought this was a good idea, delete.)
**JUNE 30, 200** (Apparently the field will only hold 12 characters, delete.)
**CHARGED OFF** (Useless, delete.)
**94 DAYS** (Take all characters preceding space and subtract from other field containing order date to obtain delinquent date.)
**94 DPD** (DPD in someones bright mind stands for Days Past Due I believe. Same as above.)
**2008-7-15 12** (Not sure what additional number is, take all characters before space and transform.)
**INVALID** (Delete.)
**BLANK** (Do nothing.)
**4/2/4/09** (Malformed date, delete.)
**1/1/009** (Same as above.)
**12282009** (Use nested LEFT and RIGHT and CONCATENATE with / in between.)
**9202011** (Add leading zero, then same as above.)
**92410** (Add leading zero, this will transform to 09/24/10)
**41261** (Days since 31/12/1899, this will transform to 12/08/12)
**1023** (Days since delinquent, subtract from ORDER DATE to get delinquent date.)
**452** (Same as above.)
**12** (Same as above.)
**1432.84** (Monetary value, mistakenly entered by low IQ lackey. Delete.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Right(Left(del(i, 1), 2), 6)` is nonsensical.

The `Left(del(i, 1), 2)` part happens first and returns a 2-character string. If you then apply `Right(..., 6)` to that 2-character string you get an error.

The `Mid` function is needed here: `Mid(del(i, 1), 3, 2)`

---

Running the `Abs` function earlier changed the array entry from being a Variant with subtype String to being a Variant with subtype Double. This shouldn't necessarily affect the Left/Mid/Right functions but try:

```
del(i, 1) = CStr(del(i, 1))
del(i, 1) = DateSerial((Right(del(i, 1), 4)), (Left(del(i, 1), 2)), (Mid(del(i, 1), 3, 2)))
```

---

We need to identify what the actual value causing the error is so:

```
If delType = "Numeric" Then
    If delChars = 8 Then
        On Error Goto DateMismatchError
        del(i, 1) = DateSerial((Right(del(i, 1), 4)), (Left(del(i, 1), 2)), (Mid(del(i, 1), 3, 2))) '<-- TYPE MISMATCH ERROR
        On Error Goto 0
    End If
End If

' at the end of your Sub or Function - I'm assuming Sub here

Exit Sub

DateMismatchError:

MsgBox "Date mismatch: error number " & Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description & _
    " caused by data value: |" & del(i, 1) & "| at row " & i & ". Original data " & _
    "value is |" & Range("AH" & i).Value2 & "|, displayed value is |" & _
    Range("AH" & i).Text & "|, number format is |" & Range("AH" & i).NumberFormat & "|"

End Sub
```

Comment: Barrowc, thanks. I applied the code, however, I still receive Error 13, Type Mismatch for that line. Does it have something to do with a possible typing mismatch between the del() array and using DateSerial?

Comment: Also, the examples given in your earlier question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/13255896/53614 - suggest that a monetary value might be the issue. For example, 12345.67 is both numeric and eight characters long but could not successfully be converted to a Date value

Comment: good pick up. I had run with the data as presented in this question.

Comment: Barrowc, I hav a much longer version of the code that filters out some of the bad datatypes. I can post it, but I was keeping this simple in the hopes of getting a quick answer.

Comment: The suggestion to use CStr still results in a Type Mismatch error. Also, commenting out the earlier Abs() call does the same.

Comment: "Date mismatch: error number 13, Type mismatch caused by data value: ||"

Comment: Slight update to output the row number when the error is found - should have included this the first time, sorry

Comment: Row 8535, which contains 1/1/009, a malformed date.

Comment: I added the Entry Templates above, so you can see which types of entries may be causing the problems.

Comment: I cannot replicate that error using that data value. If I run `Debug.Print delChars & ", " & delType & ", " & del(i, 1)` for that value I get `7, String, 1/1/009`. I've added some more output to the error handler to try and pin down this issue

Comment: Date mismatch: error number 13, Type mismatch caused by data value || at row 8853. Original data value is | 21687.36 |, displayed value is |21687.36|, number format is |General|

Comment: What is weird about that is that I have this preceding code- If del(i, 1) Like "*.*" Then del(i, 1) = Empty -to remove any monetary values.

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to select the column before hand, convert to number format 0, then copy and paste as values, before running this whole process? That would remove any decimal entries.

Comment: `If del(i, 1) Like "*.*"` should work. Further discussion will need to go to chat (won't be around until tomorrow though) or start a new question on a specific issue

Comment: Ok, I bypassed that error now by adding the following code as soon as iteration begins in the array- If del(i, 1) Like "*.*" Then del(i, 1) = Empty End If. There are still additional issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19190/discussion-between-john-ziebro-and-barrowc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this shorter code to replace your array elements with formatted dates

1. It cuts down the amount of testing inside the loop to two `IF`s. If numeric test is run first - there is no point running a longer [len](/questions/tagged/len)[int](/questions/tagged/int) test for strings that are not 8 characters
2. The string functions `Left$`, `Mid$` etc are much quicker than their variant cousins `Left`, `Mid` etc

*I have made a substituion for your `importwsRowCount` variable in the code below*

*Updated code to handle and dump results, now handles string tests and non-compliantnumbers as per barrowc comments*

The code below puts the new dates into a second array, skipping the invalid dates
The second array is then dumped at `AI``

```
Sub ReCut2()
Dim del()
Dim X()
Dim lngCnt As Long
del = Range("AH1:Ah10").Value2
ReDim X(1 To UBound(del, 1), 1 To UBound(del, 2))
Dim delChars As Long
Dim delType As String
For lngCnt = LBound(del, 1) To UBound(del, 1)
  If IsNumeric(del(lngCnt, 1)) Then
  If Len(Int((del(lngCnt, 1)))) = 8 Then X(lngCnt, 1) = DateSerial(Right$(del(lngCnt, 1), 4), Left$(del(lngCnt, 1), 2), Mid$(del(lngCnt, 1), 3, 2))
  End If
Next
[ai1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)).Value2 = X
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Brett, there are a few things I do not recognize here. What do the $s do on the "If IsNumeric..." line. Also, what is "[ai1]"?

Comment: Oh...its a column reference? I've never seen it done that way before. What are the rules on using []?

Comment: Also, in del = Range("AH1:AH10").Value2, what is .Value2 as opposed to .Value? Sorry for all the questions, I still am very new with VB.

Comment: See [this article](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/) by Charles Williams